# In PHP, how do you call an internal function from within a seperate internal function within the same function?

Tags: php, function, methods, closures

It's a bit hard to explain, but it should be clear from this example what I'm trying to do:

```
    public function onMessage($data)
    {

    if (!function_exists("sendClientToHost")) {
            $sendClientToHost = function(&$sendThis) use($type) {

                $sendThis += array('type' => $type);


            //.... execute code ....//
         };
        }

        if (!function_exists("sendObjects")) {
            $sendObjects = function() use($data) {

                $user_id = $data->user_id;


                $sendThis = array(
                "msg" => $user_id,);


                $sendClientToHost($sendThis);

            };

        }


    $sendObjects();


}
```

I try calling the internal function sendObjects within the OnMessage function, this part works. However, the sendObjects function has a critical error where it says sendClientToHost is undefined. How do I call sendClientToHost from within the sendObjects function?

Answer (score 0):

Here you are calling a function, but you have written a dollar sign at the beginnig as if it was a variable: `$sendClientToHost($sendThis);`.

Just delete the "$" and I think it should be fine...

Comment: Already tried. It's a closure, it doesn't work without the dollar sign. Because I assigned the function to the variable, that was the only way I was able to get the first nested function to work. Calling a second nested function from inside the first nested function is when things break down.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to use the closure in the other function.

$sendObjects = function() use($data, $sendClientToHost) {...};